# If a matrix $A$ is an NxN matrix and has three bases for its eigenspaces corresponding to its eigenvectors, is P guaranteed to be diagonalizable?

Tags: linear-algebra

In my textbook, a question asks if a matrix $A$ is diagonalizable. I got an answer, and when I looked to the back of book their justification was simply that $A$ (a 3x3 matrix) had three bases for its eigenspaces.

A matrix $A$ is diagonalizable if there exists some matrix $P$ such that $P A P^-1$ is a diagonal matrix.

So my question is: If an $N$x$N$ matrix $A$ has $N$ bases for its eigenspaces, is it right to assume that $A$ is diagonalizable? Is $P$ guaranteed to be invertible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

Let $U$ be the union of the bases of all eigenspaces of the $n \times n$ matrix $A$. If the vectors in $U$ are linearly independent and $|U| = n$ (i.e. there are $n$ vectors in $U$), then the elements of $U$ comprise $n$ linearly independent eigenvectors of $A$. Denote these $n$ vectors as $X_1, X_2 ... X_n$. Take $P = [X_1 X_2 ... X_n]$. $P$ is invertible since its columns are linearly independent. $PAP^{-1}$ is diagonal so therefore $A$ is diagonalizable.